# WPF - How to add an image to a uniformgrid button?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, uniformgrid

I have two images defined as follows:

```
Image Wall = new Image();
Wall.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Wall.png"));
Image Corridor = new Image();
Corridor.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Corridor.png"));
```

I have a uniform grid and in each of its cells there is a button. My goal is to make one of those pictures appear on each of those buttons based on a DataTrigger condition. My code is running but the pictures never appear and I get two warnings: "The resource "Corridor" could not be resolved" and "The resource "Wall" could not be resolved". Here is my xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding TableSize}" Columns="{Binding TableSize}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Number}" BorderThickness="0">

                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background}" Value="Corridor">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Corridor}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background}" Value="Wall">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Wall}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background}" Value="Player">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding X}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Finally this is the ObservableCollection I bound my buttongrid to. Its background property takes its value from a value called _model because I'm using MVVM architecture which is not that relevant in this question. All that matters is that Background property can only be Corridor, Wall or Player.

```
ObservableCollection<DungeonField> Fields = new ObservableCollection<DungeonField>();
for (Int32 i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    for (Int32 j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        Fields.Add(new DungeonField
        {
            Background = _model.GetField(i, j).ToString(),
            X = i,
            Y = j,
            Number = i * 9 + j,
        });
}
```

I do have these two images added to my project as resources and their Build Action is set to Resource. I'm quite a newbie at manipulating pictures in wpf so my question is what am I missing?

Thanks In Advance

Edit:
I figured I shouldn't use DynamicResource in xaml in the DataTrigger part because I already declared an Image variable so I can just Bind it to the buttons. Using Binding instead of DynamicResource makes all of those warnings disappear but the pictures still don't show up in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I do not need to declare those two images at the start of my question and the first two DataTriggers should look like this inside:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background}" Value="Corridor">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/Corridor.png" />
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background}" Value="Wall">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/Wall.png" />
</DataTrigger>
```